# PHP 7.2 - Include file cannot access another include file

Tags: php, include

I am having an issue with an include file accessing another include file (my db connection)

I have a site with the following layout ::

```
root/conn.php :: db connection file  
root/site/file1.php :: regular page  
root/site/include/func.inc :: file with functions in it
```

Each file is listed below with appropriate code...

conn.php ::

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'mydb';
$user = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypass';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    $conn->set_charset($charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
unset($host, $db, $user, $pass, $charset);

?>
```

---

file1.php ::

```
include_once ("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/conn.php");
include_once ("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/site/include/func.inc");
{ code that calls functions in func.php }
```

---

func.inc ::

```
include_once ("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/conn.php");
{ various functions }
```

---

When I browse to /file1.php, I get the following error ::

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: conn in C:\inetpub\root\site\include\func.inc on line 231
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\inetpub\root\site\include\func.inc:231
```

my func.inc file cannot seem to find the conn.php file.  I have also tried removing the include function from func.inc.  There are other files in the /include folder that can access the conn.php file with the same include function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue relates to something called the `variable scope` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
==> Please read that to get detailed information

The second example describes your problem

#### func.inc

```
<?php
include_once ("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/conn.php");    
// to illustrate the issue, the include can be simplified to 
// $conn = "something";  // => global scope variable

function myFunc(){
    echo $conn; //no output - $conn exists ONLY in the local scope --> not available inside thisfunction
}
```

### Solution 1:

#### func.inc

```
<?php
function myFunc($conn){
    echo $conn; //outputs $conn
}
```

#### file1.php

```
<?php
include_once ("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/conn.php");
include_once ("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/site/include/func.inc");

//call function and pass the $conn, it's available here in the global scope
myFunc($conn);
```

### Solution 2

but keep in mind `global` is considered as bad practice

#### func.inc

```
<?php
include_once ("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/conn.php");    

function myFunc(){
    global $conn; //$conn is declared global in the local scope of this function
    echo $conn; //outputs $conn from conn.php if you call myFunc from anywhere
}
```